# Plotly Cufflinks keys

Tags: python, plotly, heatmap, plotly-python

Using chloropeth/choromap and would like to heatmap UK by postal areas, towns in particular.  Where can I find the list of references for the 'LOCATIONs =' and 'LOCATIONMODE = ' options when defining the data using:

data = dict(type = 'chloropeth', 
            locations = 
            locationmode = 
            colorscale = 
            text = 
            z=
            colorbar = )

searching stackoverflow, plot.ly and other sites for a list of possible geographic options.

code shown above - standard notation for plot.ly cufflinks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the reference for the allowed values of `locationmode`: https://plot.ly/python/reference/#choropleth-locationmode

As of today you can supply country references in ISO-3 or full name format or US state names in full format. No other geometries are supported today and there is no way with a `choropleth` trace to supply your own geometry.

That said, with the `choroplethmapbox` trace type, the geometry can be supplied as GeoJSON and you can index it however you like: https://plot.ly/python/mapbox-county-choropleth/